# Pandas - Filtering None Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to explore some datasets. I have this dataframe:

[image]

I want to exclude any row that has a value in column `City`. So I've tried:

```
new_df = all_df[(all_df["City"] == "None") ]
new_df
```

But then I got an empty dataframe:

[image]

It works whenever I use any value other than `None`. Any idea how to filter this dataframe?

Comment: Use `None` without quotes

Comment: @MichaelO. I tried it.. same result

Comment: Try then `all_df["City"] is None`

Comment: Why is it `None` at all? Is it an actual string `"None"`? For me it's `NaN` if I fill DataFrame with `None` values.

Comment: @tarashypka it was a one column (Region\City\Village) that i split it up into 3 using "all_df[['Region', 'City', 'Village']] = all_df['Cities_Full_Name'].str.split('\\', expand=True)"

Comment: @Shadin Yes, my bad, actually it fills it with `NaN` values if data type is numeric, if data type is mixed (object) then there will be `None` values.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Consider using `isnull()` to locate missing values

```
all_df[all_df['City'].isnull()]
```

Comment: To exclude those rows: all_df[~all_df['City'].isnull()]

Comment: @fstang You can also use notnull: `all_df[all_df['City'].notnull()]`

Comment: `isnull()` returns True for both `None` and `NaN` values.

Answer (score 6):

Try this to select only the `None` values for city column:

```
new_df = all_df['City'][all_df['City'] == "None"]
```

Try this to see all other columns which has the same rows of `'City'==None`

```
new_df = all_df[all_df['City'] == "None"]
print(new_df.head()) # with function head() you can see the first 5 rows
```

Comment: Thanks! but when i print the new df i get: Series([], Name: City, dtype: object)

Comment: How can i print it properly?

Comment: Ok, I think I got your question. You need to print all other columns as well for city==None.
I have edited the codes. Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Didn't worked for me. @mr.tarsa response worked.

Answer (score 2):

1. `None` is a keyword, not a string, so don't use quotes.
2. `None == None` gives `True`, but in custom classes the comparison operator can be overridden, so it's safer to use `is None`.
3. Pandas provides the [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html#pandas.isna) function. So I suggest:

```py
new_df = all_df[all_df['City'].isna()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [3]: all_df.query('City != City')
Out[3]: 
   FACTS_Value    Region  City Village
0      34135.0  Al Bahah  None    None
```

Answer (score 1):

Method to extract all the values other than None given its column name.

```
df = df[df.columnname.notna()]
```

Comment: this solution is incorrect. None and Na are 2 different values.

Answer (score 0):

I hope "`where`" can do what you expect

```
new_df = new_df.where(new_df["city"], None)
```

And it is better use `np.nan` rather than `None`.

For more details [pandas.DataFrame.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Comment: How about getting all that is not None?

Comment: @Nabin `all_df[~all_df['City'].isnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

If it's desired to filter multiple rows with None values, we could use `any`, `all` or `sum`. For example, for `df` given below:

```
   FACTS_Value    Region      City  Village
0        16482  Al Bahah      None     None
1        22522  Al Bahah   Al Aqiq     None
2        12444  Al Bahah   Al Aqiq  Al Aqiq
3        12823  Al Bahah  Al Bahah  Al Aqiq
4        11874      None      None     None
```

If we want to select all rows with None value in *at least one* column, we could use `isna` + `any` on axis to build a boolean mask:

```
msk = df.isna().any(axis=1)
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
   FACTS_Value    Region     City Village
0        16482  Al Bahah     None    None
1        22522  Al Bahah  Al Aqiq    None
4        11874      None     None    None
```

If we want the rows where *all* non-numeric column values are None, then we could use `isna` + `all` on axis:

```
msk = df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').isna().all(axis=1)
```

or

```
msk = df[['Region', 'City', 'Village']].isna().all(axis=1)
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
   FACTS_Value Region  City Village
4        11874   None  None    None
```

If we want to filter rows where there are exactly `n` None values, then we could use `sum` on axis + `eq`:

```
msk = df.isna().sum(axis=1) == 2
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
   FACTS_Value    Region  City Village
0        16482  Al Bahah  None    None
```

Answer (score 0):

Given, where `None` is python `None`, not `'None'`:

```
   FACTS_Value    Region      City  Village
0        16482  Al Bahah      None     None
1        22522  Al Bahah   Al Aqiq     None
2        12444  Al Bahah   Al Aqiq  Al Aqiq
3        12823  Al Bahah  Al Bahah  Al Aqiq
4        11874      None      None     None
```

Fix your `None` values:

```
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
```

Now the following works as expected:

```
df[df.City.isna()]
```