# pandas df[df["A"]==None] is not the same as df["A"].values==None

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Assume I have a dataframe `df` where the column `A` consists of 10 `None` and the rest is something else.

If I do the slicing `df=df[df["A"]==None]` I get a wrong result. I figured out that `df["A"]==None` returns `False` (even when the elements are `None`) but `df["A"].values==None` returns the correct.

How come? Shouldn't we be able to slice in the first way ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117272/pandas-filtering-none-values

Comment: use `df=df[df["A"].isnull()]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `isna()` method over the serie.

For your case:

```
df = df.loc[df['A'].isna()]
```

Comment: To explain the two different answers, the `df.isna()` and `df.isnull()` do the same thing -- they are aliases

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follows

```
df = df[df['A'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is why the first approach does not work