# How to select data from a pandas DataFrame that meet conditions A or B?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I saw good posts that perfectly answer my title question (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)), but I am in a more specific situation.

Let's say I have the following very simple DataFrame

```
df.head()

   param  accuracy
0    None       98
1    4.0        100
2    5.0        95
3    6.0        87
4    7.0        56
5    8.0        45
6    9.0        59
7    None       96
...
```

I would like to restrict my DataFrame to data where param is either None or 4. I tried the following technique

```
params = [None, 4]
df = df[df['param'].isin(params)]
```

which only selects data where param is 4.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117272/pandas-filtering-none-values) shows how to filter None values with `isnull()` method, but it is not compatible with `isin()`... Hence my question.

Comment: I dont think you can use ```isin``` in this scenario, as ```None``` == ```None``` will return False. Tthe isnull and isna methods should help in this case

Comment: I think your problem is that the None value of the param attribute is defined as String. If you define it as None (nan) it will be erased with your code. If not the answer of @alexander is valid.

Comment: Thanks @IMB, it works if I use params=["None", 4]. I did not realize that my None were String..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @IMB, a solution is to do `params = ["None", 4]` instead of `params = [None, 4]`.

My dataframe was initially containing NaN, which I transformed into None with `df = df.fillna('None')`. Hence the String type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "and" and "or" operations on the selectors and construct new ones. Would this help in your case?

```
params = [4]
df = df[df['param'].isin(params) | df['param'].isnull()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[ (df['param'] == 4) | (df['param'].isna()) ]
```