# 'NoneType' object is not callable when tryna do a histogram on datafram

Tags: python, dataframe

```
rfm = df3.groupby('CustomerID').agg({
    'InvoiceNo' : lambda num: len(num),
    'TotalSum' : lambda price: price.sum(), 
    'InvoiceDay': lambda x: ref_date- x.max()})

rfm.rename(columns={
    'InvoiceNo' : 'Frequency',
    'TotalSum' : 'Monetary', 
    'InvoiceDay': 'Recency'
}, inplace=True)

rfm['Recency'] = rfm['Recency'].dt.days

rfm.hist()
plt.show()
```

It keeps showing this error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I was expecting a histogram plot of the 3 different variables. If I don't have `rfm.hist(column= 'Recency')`, it still shows the same error. What is the issue here?

These are the `dtypes`:

```
Frequency      int64
Monetary     float64
Recency        int64
```

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:459, in finfo.**new**(cls, dtype)
458 try:
--> 459     dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
460 except TypeError:
461     # In case a float instance was given

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/Downloads/Unclassified Learning/Unclassified Learning.ipynb Cell 25 in <cell line: 2>()
1 rfm.hist()
----> 2 plt.show()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:389, in show(*args, **kwargs)
345 """
346 Display all open figures.
347
(...)
386 explicitly there.
387 """
388 _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
...
--> 462     dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
464 obj = cls._finfo_cache.get(dtype, None)
465 if obj is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Put error message in code block, please

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to figure out what moment it happens as we need the whole error log. But that error is trying to tell you that you are invoking a method on a None type. Meaning that some of the attributes return `None`, and you are still trying to access them.

To debug, recommend checking the pandas DataFrame first, printing out `rfm.head()`.

Secondly, if this is happening while calling `hist()`, probably some of the underlying data is `None`, and might be worth investing some time into cleaning up these None rows, or filling them up with something.

Comment: Hi, I see. I have included the error log, could you help me take a look? I would really appreciate it thank you! Also I am having the same error when importing KMeans from sklearn.cluster

Comment: @shim this seems to be happening while calling .hist(), which in turn calls numpy. Still suspect that the underlying dataframe does have some None type values. Can you verify this `df[df['Recency'].isnull()]` for example (check more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117272/pandas-filtering-none-values)